# Checkbox conditional rendering after action is performed - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

In order to have my check boxes on click i get the document/box id and the document number . Like this :

```
handleCheckboxClick = (e) => {
    let parsedVal = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
    let newDocList = { ...this.state.docList };
    if (e.target.checked) {
        newDocList[parsedVal.documentId] = parsedVal.documentNumber;
    } else {
        delete newDocList[parsedVal.documentId];
    }
    this.setState({
        docList: newDocList,
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.docList)
    });
};
```

After that when I do a call to the back end it returns me a pdf's which I convert into a ZIP file and after that, I automatically download them for the user. Besides that, I get the JSON response with the downloaded document ID's . 
My goal is to disable my check boxes when a document I downloaded. At the moment I have this :

```
 .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                downloadedIDS : response.data.downloadedIds
            })
```

And this is the result ouput in the console.log

[image]

Further more my Checkbox is treating the disable like this :

```
  <Checkbox disabled ={ downloadedIDS > 0 && true }
            color='default' 
            value={JSON.stringify({documentId:rowData.documentId,documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })} 
            onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick} />
```

And I end up with result that each one of the boxes no matter selected or not are disabled. So I ask myself what am I doing wrong ? Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: When do you want to disable your checkbox?

Comment: @ShivratnaKumar after the response from the back end . Or from my side when the download button is clicked and user recieves the ZIP i want to disable the downloaded documents ( or the previously selected i should say )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting your condition correctly, you can do something like this:-

```
<Checkbox disabled={downloadedIDS && downloadedIDS.indexOf(rowData.documentId) >= 0 ? true : false}
     color='default' 
     value={JSON.stringify({documentId:rowData.documentId,documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })} 
     onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
/>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this will not help me at all . Because the app is crashing after this change.

Comment: `Invoices.js:585 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @PandaMastr I have updated my answer `{downloadedIDS && downloadedIDS.length ? true : false}`, please check.

Comment: @PandaMastr I have the disable condition as `disabled={downloadedIDS && downloadedIDS.indexOf(rowData.documentId) >= 0 ? true : false}`.  Please try this.

Comment: Update your answer so i can mark it as working . Thanks mate !

Comment: It has some strange behaiviour . Actually when you select for example two checkboxes and hit the download after they are disabled ( which is ok ) , but after that if you select three more for example the previous two are enabled again ...

Answer (score 1):

`downloadedIDS` is the state object key .SO you need call `this.state.downloadedIDS`

```
<Checkbox disabled={this.state.downloadedIDS && this.state.downloadedIDS.length > 0 ? true : false}
     color='default' 
     value={JSON.stringify({documentId:rowData.documentId,documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })} 
     onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
/>
```

**Updated**

You need trigger getZip function while `componentMount`.Add the code on invoices.

```
componentMount(){
 this.getZip()
}
```

And remove the do string on end of `response.data.downloadedIds`

```
this.setState({
          downloadedIDS: response.data.downloadedIds
        });
```

And add constructor on class start

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({
      downloadedIDS: []
    });
  }
```

Comment: there is no need to call this.state if i have declared it after my render like `const { downloadedIDS } = this.state` . I got the same result all the check boxes are disabled ( no matter selected or not ) after the document is downloaded

Comment: ok can you provide working sanbox to me https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: i have tried to create a sandbox , but it doesn't work .

Comment: can you share that sandbox link

Comment: your sandbox was empty.please save the code before sandbox share

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-wright-sjlg1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

It should be okey now

Comment: It still disable all of the check boxes . The Answer above works . But it has some issues . When you select two check boxes for example and hit the download button its ok , but after that if you select three more the first two are enabled again .